# Why does multiplying positive numbers result in negative values?

Tags: java, overflow

for certain inputs like 5,10,10, there are negative values in the output.this is a program in which series of numbers are created by multiplying adjacent numbers.I am a java beginner,please help me to modify my code accordingly.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        int a=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number");
        int b=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the no of terms");
        int c=in.nextInt();
        if(a>0 && b>0 && c>0)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<c+2; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(a + ",");
                int mul=a*b;
                a=b;
                b=mul;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }


    }
}
```

```
Enter first number
5
Enter the second number
10
Enter the no of terms
10
5,
10,
50,
500,
25000,
12500000,
-1032612608,
-975265792,
1931476992,
0,
0,
0,
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the numbers you have entered and the output you get.

Comment: What is expected output from the program?

Comment: use long instead of int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the value of an `int` overflows, it starts from the other end i.e. once you cross the maximum value an `int` can hold, it will start from the minimum limit of `int`. The same happens for underflows as well. Check the following program to understand it better:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int y = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(x + 1);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(y - 1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483648
2147483647
```

For bigger integer calculations, you should use `long`. For even bigger integer calculations, you need [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L;
        long y = Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1L;
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2147483647
2147483648
-2147483648
-2147483649
```

Comment: Correct. And to add to that, in the example in the question, the result of 25000 * 12500000 is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, causing the overflow.